# File upload with the ability to resume (preferably in Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, scripting, file-upload

this is quite a difficult topic by all accounts. I am building a website that requires users to upload large (multi-GB). What is the best way allow users to upload a file on a website and allow the file upload to be resumed should it fail? What is the way to write this in rails?

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Max.

Comment: I am unaware of any browsers that allow resuming of interrupted uploads. Given that, this question may be much more difficult than you think to answer. Perhaps a plugin or flash is the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No browsers support resuming uploads.

From my Googling, Flash doesn't seem to, either.

Though I don't know enough about Java to say it's impossible, there don't seem to be any pre-rolled upload solutions that support this method.

In short, you would have to code your own out-of-browser/plugin solution. If that is not feasible, you may have to abandon this feature. Sorry!

EDIT: Actually, after using a better search query, here's a Java solution that seems to support this through partitioning the initial file: [JumpLoader](http://jumploader.com/index.html). Here is the [documentation page for resuming downloads](http://jumploader.com/doc_resume.html). Best of luck! (You will note that there are purchase links - this is only for an unbranded version, and for the source code. You can use the JumpLoader branded version for free.)

Answer (score 1):

**No browser support this, In fact this cannot be done over HTTP.**

You will have to write your own java **applet**, **ActiveX** control or **WPF browser application** to achieve this. Any of this will speak to a TCP server listening on the server side to achieve pause-and-resume upload of file.

Answer (score 1):

Six years since you asked, but for future viewers, take a look at [ResumableJS](http://www.resumablejs.com).  It uses HTML5 File API to break uploads into chunks.   They also include a [RoR example](https://github.com/23/resumable.js/blob/master/samples/Backend%20on%20Ruby%20On%20Rails.md) for accepting the upload.