# Resume large file uploads in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, large-files, resume

Rails v. 2.3.8

The sites I manage handle a lot of large (video) file uploads. On occasion during the upload process, the connection gets lost and the user has to restart the video upload. What I am looking to do is to be able to resume the video upload in this case. What are some suggestions on ways to manage this?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [File upload with the ability to resume (preferably in Ruby on Rails)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977927/file-upload-with-the-ability-to-resume-preferably-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 0):

This *might* not be a Rails issue. But I came across [jQuery FileUpload UI](http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload) a while back and saw that it has support for resuming uploads. It seems, based on the description in their [features](http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload#features) page, that it's a browser issue.